# salesforce lightning $A.get("e.force:createRecord") it's return empty

Tags: javascript, salesforce, visualforce, salesforce-lightning

I tried in salesforce softphone.

```
var createAcountContactEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
createAcountContactEvent.setParams({
      "entityApiName": "contact",
      "defaultFieldValues": {
            'Phone' : '415-240-6590',
            'Mobile' : '001xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
       }
});
createAcountContactEvent.fire();
```

I have created the component in my salesforce arc. How can i use the component in visualforce page?

```
$A.get("e.force:createRecord") // Its return nothing.
```

how to solve the issue?
The below is displayed.

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action
>   failed: c:MyContactList$controller$createAccount [Cannot read property
>   'setParams' of undefined] Failing descriptor:
>   {c:MyContactList$controller$createAccount}

Comment: Are you using lightning out ? Also i suggest you post the question on salesforce.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: yes. using lightning out.

Answer (score 0):

None of the standard lightning will work when you embed it in VF Page (using lightning out). You need to handle these actions explicitly. You can refer below mentione links for more details.

http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2018/04/toast-message-from-visualforce-page.html
https://www.soliantconsulting.com/blog/handle-lightning-events-from-a-visualforce-page/

Hope this info is helpful!

Comment: Rather than linking to external URL, please add relevant code and explanation in the answer.